# Merging several <script> tags into one in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

Consider a following piece of HTML code:

```
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<div>...</div>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
<script>...</script>
<script>...</script>
```

I would like to merge the script sections into one as follows:

```
<script>...</script>
<div>...</div>
<script>...</script>
<style>...</style>
<script>...</script>
```

I tried this piece of code:

```
while (true) {
    val newSource = source.replace(
                "[<]script[>](.*?)[<]/script[>]\\s*[<]script[>]"
                     .toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.MULTILINE, RegexOption.DOT_MATCHES_ALL)), 
                "<script>$1</script>")

    if (source.equals(newSource)) {
        break;
    }
    source = newSource
}
```

It is not elegant and not working :-)

1. I would like to avoid the loop. Can I write a regular expression to process the whole code?
2. This will actually lead to only single `<script>...</script>` as it will consume both the `<div>` and `<style>` in the middle. How can I forbid the contents containing tags?

Comment: It's a age old thing, repeated again and again: You can't use regular expressions to reliably parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags Use an HTML parser library such as JSoup. It's much easier.

Comment: I am not trying to parse it fully. I just want to search for ALL `<X>Z</X>` where `Z` does contain `<Y>`. Or even more simply `XZX` where `Z` doesn't contain `Y`.

Comment: You do want to parse it fully. What if one of the scripts contains `var example = "</script>";`? What if there's a `<script src="..."></script>` in between? Use a proper parser. It is much, much easier and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var source="""
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        <div>...</div>
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        <style>...</style>
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        """
     source = source.replace(
                "[<]/script[>]\\s*[<]script[>]"
                     .toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.MULTILINE, RegexOption.DOT_MATCHES_ALL)), 
                "\n")
     println(source)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not good enough as there are `<script type="x-template">` and general `<script>`. These cannot be merged.

Comment: this does not merge them